# I need to register a dynamic route in Global.asax file

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, routes, global-asax

I store my Page details in Menu Table as

```
MenuName, MenuID, ParentID, PageURL, PageHandler 
Home, 1, 0, /,Default.aspx 
About Us, 2, 0, /about-us/, About.aspx 
Contact, 3, 0, /contact/, contact.aspx 
Mission, 4, 2, /about-us/mission/, About.aspx
Vision, 5, 2, /about-us/vision/, About.aspx
```

If i code my Route as static in Global.asax file then it works fine as show below.

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {
    routes.MapPageRoute("en_Home", "default/", "~/default.aspx", false,
            new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
            });

     routes.MapPageRoute("en_aboutUs", "about-us/", "~/about_us.aspx", false,
            new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
            });
}
```

I want  my Routes to be Dynamic so that i can read the URL and PageHandler value from Database and pass it to Route in Global.asax file as

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
 {          
    string sURL = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    //Above Statement give error Say "HttpContext.Current Cant be used in this context

    string PageHandler =  DataProvider.GetPageHandlerByPageURL(sURL);

     routes.MapPageRoute("en_General_Page", sURL, PageHandler, false,
            new RouteValueDictionary {
            { "path", "page-not-found" },{ "pagename", "page-not-found" }
            });     
 }
```

I am not getting any success in this as i have to pass `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` value to another function so that i can get the page handler. It fails with error `Cant use HttpCotext in this context`

`HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath` doesnt work in Route `RegisterRoutes` function i have to define same in `Application_BeginRequest` but then it has its own issue.

How can i achieve dynamic routing in my case. I am using `ASP.Net Webform 4.5`

I would appreciate help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Dynamic Routing in ASP.NET Cheers:)-

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RegisterRoute(RouteTable.Routes);
        }

        public void RegisterRoute(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("T");
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Head", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Desc", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Url", typeof(string)));

            DataRow dr0 = dt.NewRow();
            dr0["Head"] = "Default";
            dr0["Desc"] = "D/D";
            dr0["Url"] = "~/Default.aspx";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr0);

            DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
            dr1["Head"] = "ERP1";
            dr1["Desc"] = "ERP/ERP1";
            dr1["Url"] = "~/ERP/ERP1.aspx";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

            DataRow dr2 = dt.NewRow();
            dr2["Head"] = "ERP2";
            dr2["Desc"] = "ERP/ERP2";
            dr2["Url"] = "~/ERP/ERP2.aspx";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr2);

            DataRow dr3 = dt.NewRow();
            dr3["Head"] = "W";
            dr3["Desc"] = "W/W";
            dr3["Url"] = "~/WebForm1.aspx";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr3);

            foreach (DataRow d in dt.Rows)
            {
                routes.MapPageRoute(d["Head"].ToString(), d["Desc"].ToString(), d["Url"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confusing me;

Ill gladly answer the question, just put the urls as they would appear in the web browser.

e.g.

"http://localhost/Home"

"http://localhost/about-us"

"http://localhost/about-us/mission"

"http://localhost/about-us/vission"

It seems like you are not understanding how to register routes.

i do not follow;

```
   MenuName, MenuID, ParentID, PageURL, PageHandler 
    Home, 1, 0, /,Default.aspx 
    About Us, 2, 0, /about-us/, About.aspx 
    Contact, 3, 0, /contact/, contact.aspx 
    Mission, 4, 2, /about-us/mission/, About.aspx
    Vision, 5, 2, /about-us/vision/, About.aspx
```

**I will update my answer** when you have told me the info i need.

**Update**

seems like my understanding of ASP.Net Webform may be different. 
Why arnt  you using

```
   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

instead of ....

```
 routes.MapPageRoute(
     routeName: "SomeRouteName",
     routeUrl: "GuessingHardset",
     physicalFile: "~/about_us.aspx", //also hard set
     checkPhysicalUrlAccess: false
 );
```

**Update**

my apologies they are different.

This link is great:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/url-routing-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series

something like....

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "en_aboutUs",
    "about-us/{subpage}",
    "~/about_us.aspx",
    false
});

void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Retrive subpage param from "about-us/{subpage}" URL
    string subpage = Page.RouteData.Values["subpage"] as string;
}
```

Comment: This is ASp.net webform what you are showing me is for MVC i think..  Besides this i want my PhysicalFile to value to come from database. In your case it is static.